# What is this error I am getting "Uncaught Error: "version" is a required argument." when running unit tests in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

[The console snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wONDr.png)

Has anyone encountered this issue and what was your solution? I searched the whole internet and could not fix this. This is what I found out:

I get this error message instead of a detailed description of why the unit test is failing, and this happens only in a few components, not every component. I will give a few examples.

I was testing a simple method that returns a boolean based on a condition and was getting this error. The way I fixed the issue was that I had forgotten to set the property I was using in the condition to a mocked object and when I set it, it passed. That is fine, but previously in other components I was getting an error like "Cannot read property "someProperty" of undefined".

Another example. I was testing a method that calculates a discount. I had written a test that was expecting some value and let's say I was expecting a discount of 5.35. The test was fine, until I had to round this discount value. I changed the logic and of course the test will fail, but it failed with that exact error "version is required", instead of "expecting 5.00 but got 5.35".

Another big issue is when I do a big logic change based on a change request and I get around 20-30 failing tests with that message and do not know why they are failing. Or when I am testing more complex method and do not know what I am missing in the test.

I am afraid I cannot share the code, but I think it's clear from the description. If you need something, please ask and I'll try to provide it. Until now, I tried to resolve it so I checked the versions of different tools, npm, node, cli, karma, configurations, running with source-map set to false, removing some imports of the component's spec file etc.

Comment: can you share console snapshot of error ?

Comment: Yes, just posted it.. but it only that, the error message. @LogicBlower

Comment: there is any property or function argument --version -- that exists in files that is in component or any related imported file that is used as dependency (in constructor)

Comment: I searched for "version" in the whole project but did not find any property. I will do it again manually within the component and its imported dependencies since you think it may be it. Thanks.